# Learning Design for UI and Website Design

Tags: user-interface

I'm current a computer science student with a minor in psychology.  I have the programming down when it comes to software design, but not so much the design of UI.  What are some good books/websites/blogs for learning design principles for user interfaces and/or websites?

Comment: If I were you I would just copy stackoverflow. ;-)

Comment: Haha.  Yeah, I was really impressed with it's design too.  I'd love to learn what it takes to design similar pages in the future.  :)

Answer (score 12):

A must read: [Don't Make Me Think](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321344758)

Comment: Yep, +1.  Full of simple, to the point, easy to read, common sense UI techniques that everyone should be using.  And it's a fun read too!

Comment: Personally, I found 'Don't Make Me Think' a little out-of-date, regardless of the author's claim that the data is timeless. The book itself certainly isn't well designed, which makes me even more hesitant. 'UI techniques' and 'HCI Methods' are very useful, but not the same as interface/interaction design (in my opinion).

Answer (score 7):

I'd look at [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com) and [Signals vs. Noise](http://37signals.com/svn) for good advice, but learning about design is about exposing yourself to a lot of good and bad design — look at really well designed websites (like those made by [HappyCog](http://happycog.com), [SimpleBits](http://simplebits.com), or [Airbag Industries](http://airbagindustries.com)). Look at all the people who work there, their blogs, their work, their books — be inspired but never copy.

I'd also be wary of sites dedicated exclusively to 'user experience' design or 'usability', many of the principles of design have nothing to do with user testing, studies or HCI, and focusing to much on those things can lead to development of methodologies rather than sense. I'd recommend taking a class in communication design and learning about type. Good design starts with type and hierarchy — [Thinking With Type](http://www.papress.com/other/thinkingwithtype/index.htm) is a great introductory book. Also read about grid systems and gestalt psychology.

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

The consummate book on UI design is *[Don't Make Me Think](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321344758)*. Additionally, *[The Design of Everyday Things](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0465067107)* is enlightening though it is not specifically about UI design.

That said, my experience with UI design has been primarily focused on web applications. I have found the work by [Dan Cederholm](http://simplebits.com/about/) to be the most enlightening in designing excellent user interfaces for the web. One of the most important aspects of web design is ensuring semantically correct accessible sites and Cederholm does an excellent job describing how to do that in *[Web Standards Solutions](http://astore.amazon.com/simplebits-20/detail/1590593812)* which was followed by the also excellent *[Bulletproof Web Design](http://astore.amazon.com/simplebits-20/detail/0321509021)*.

Though the [CSS Zen Garden](http://csszengarden.com/) may not be explicitly about UI design it is an outstanding example of what can be accomplished visually through CSS-based design.

Finally, an often overlooked part of UI design is delivering effective error messages. While, *[Defensive Design for the Web](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073571410X)* emphasizes web error design much of what is described is applicable to other mediums. Those responsible for the book [37Signals](http://37signals.com/) maintain an excellent blog [Signal vs. Noise](http://www.37signals.com/svn).

Comment: penultimate -
1 : next to the last <the penultimate chapter of a book>
2 : of or relating to a penult <a penultimate accent>
which means I've used the word incorrectly. :)

Answer (score 2):

Essentially all you need to know about UX and how to become part of it: http://whitneyhess.com/blog/2009/06/30/so-you-wanna-be-a-user-experience-designer-step-1-resources/

Answer (score 2):

Jakob Nielsen 's [Useit.com](http://useit.com). Lot's of works there, and basically it is about the usability engineering (ie, not on aesthetic side of design), which is quite controversial to many web designers.

[A List apart](http://alistapart.com) provides a great bunch of tips and tricks and also articles on web layout and design.

Answer (score 2):

[Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/tag/design/) (new articles daily) covers many topics which include many good quality design articles. [Usability Post](http://www.usabilitypost.com/) also has some quality material, although it isn't updated all that frequently.

Answer (score 2):

just follow SMASHINGMAGAZINE .. best on internet

Answer (score 1):

One of the best ways to get better at UI design is to look around. Look at the design of web sites / applications with a critical eye.

See what you like and don't like about different elements of these sites. Over time, this will make you a much better web designer.

Answer (score 0):

One more book that would be helpful is "The Design of Everyday Things" by Donald.A. Norman. Though not about GUI design perse this book talks about design in general and how best some of the everyday things we are exposed to (say doors) can be better designed so that there isn't a need for explicit instructions to do obvious things that an object (say door) is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

[Designing Interfaces](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008031) by Jenifer Tidwell is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

**The principle of beautiful web design** is a great book.
A must read........

http://www.sitepoint.com/books/design1/

Answer (score 0):

I really like [Designing the Obvious](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032145345X).  It has a lot of good, simple ideas and it's short enough to read in a day or two to get the feel and then reread later to let more sink in.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also find some answers (including mine) at [this recent Stack Overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125350/what-is-necessary-to-become-a-professional-web-designer)

My must-read list includes:

- *The Non-Designer's Design Book*
- *The Elements of Typographic Style*
- *Designer's Color Manual* ad/or *Light and Color in Nature and Art*
- Almost anything by Wucius Wong, particularly *Principles of Form and Design*
- *Meggs' History of Graphic Design*, and/or *Graphic Design History* by Steven Heller
- The works of Edward Tufte
- *Information Architecture* (Rosenfeld)
- *Designing Interfaces* (Tidwell)
- Be familiar with Jakob Nielsen's work but don't let it run your life
- [Michael Angeles' website, urlgreyhot](http://urlgreyhot.com/personal/)
- [Khoi Vinh's website, Subtraction](http://subtraction.com/)

Answer (score 0):

A book that a friend of mine is reading is Elements of Design: A Graphical Style Guide.  I figured I'd just mention it here.

Answer (score 0):

Get a copy of [Designed for Use](http://pragprog.com/book/lmuse/designed-for-use) by Lukas Mathis.

Worth reading to the very end.