# what are best initial things that i must know in order to jump in to asp.net development

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am doing Windows base programing using C# from last 8 months and you can put me in Level 8 in C# out of 10. Now time come to switch to Web programming and get some more ingredients to my expertises.So i want to know what are best initial things that i must know in order to jump in to asp.net development.I know it is to diffrent as compared to desktop programming but is there any migrating Handout available out there??

Thanks in advance

Lura

Comment: I think the best way to learn is to start coding. Follow some free tutorials/walk-throughs: http://www.asp.net/get-started

Comment: www.asp.net - watch all the videos. done.

Answer (score 7):

there can be lot of concepts to learn to do proper web based development but for starter

1- What is Stateless feature ?

2- What is Session ?

3- What is viewState if not planning to use asp.net MVC?

4- What is Request / Response model?

5- Asp.Net Page Life Cycle.

6- What is caching?

7- A basic JavaScript course.

8- What is GET/POST method?

this is not the final list but as a starter this can be considered.

Comment: A good list! What I think is most confusing moving to from being a "normal" to web development is to consider the Stateless factor. And a good understanding of the ASP.Net Page Life Cycle and here is a good link for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 4):

this is one of those "it depends" answers.

The thing with .Net is, if you have the IDE (Visual Studio), you can develop not only ASP.Net pages, you can also pursue Forms Applications, WPF, Silverlight, Services, etc. What would matter is which programming language to use in .Net (C#, VB.Net).

I would suggest prioritize in what you want to focus. Some ASP.Net noobs I worked with focused too much on the HTML/GUI side, while there's nothing wrong mastering it, they tend to compromise basic OOP skills. You have to understand, the reason why you're using ASP.Net versus a static HTML page is you want your web pages to become "dynamic". In order to achieve that, you have to do back-end programming and not just markups and javascript. Forget about the drag-n-drop objects shown in the tutorials, if you work in a corporate/professional environment, you'll barely use those.

I started learning HTML when I was 15 (i'm now 27) and those years of experience made my HTML & Javascript coding as trivial tasks and I was able to focus more on the C# logic.

The problem though with starting of as a Windows Forms programmer is, they usually had to learn developing web sites the hard way. Some fail to understand the concepts of Page Lifecycle and the limited states that ASP.Net offer. If they're using ASP.Net Forms, they almost automatically abuse ViewState objects to achieve what they want, and abuse the ASP.Net AJAX control.

Try to find a balance between those two scenarios and you'll be alright. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

For me the initial thinks to start the web programming are

1. Learn about html creating pages.
2. Familiar your self with the way a page load to the client, what other info send, what return etc.
3. Learn javascript, and probably jQuery for the client programming.
4. Learn about the media on the web, mostly images is the one you need. How to create them and user them to develop a page.

Some other answer to consider.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393639/best-web-programming-book-for-stand-alone-application-guy
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861290/web-application-book-for-dummies-managers
[Good Web Designing Books for Programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672024/good-web-designing-books-for-programmers)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158769/best-books-to-learn-about-design
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516424/book-recommendation-web-user-interface-design
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034758/what-are-the-best-web-design-sites
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884/good-javascript-books
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655530/best-javascript-book-for-an-experienced-coder

ps
I am working from 1995 with web pages in general, but I am unable to know my level, because to tell you the truth, I do not know what and how is the level 10.

Answer (score 2):

I would have gone with the following path ...

- HTML / HTML5
- Understanding HTTP request/response
- CSS / CSS3
- JavaScript and Ajax (including classical and prototypical inheritance, closure, FP)
- A bit about web design  (Check Pragmatic press  http://pragprog.com/titles/bhgwad/web-design-for-developers
- For general web related things  check out http://nettuts.com
- AJAX
- jQuery
- ASP.NET Lifecycle/ Server Control /UserControl, HTTPModules, HTTPHandlers, Session, Caching etc
- Firefox dev environmnet + Firebug addon + YSlow

Hope you find this useful.