# Wants to switch to web development

Tags: language-agnostic

I am a QA engineer, wants to switch to web development..I have done some projects in my academic life in C & C# but all are desktop based applications..dont know from where to take a start with?

Comment: This is a more appropriate discussion for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [what are best initial things that i must know in order to jump in to asp.net development.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544074/what-are-best-initial-things-that-i-must-know-in-order-to-jump-in-to-asp-net-deve)

Comment: @WillHughes: no, Programmers isn't open (anymore) to career advice either.

Answer (score 3):

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) is a pretty good resource. You should start with HTML and CSS, then move on to PHP and Javascript, then databases (MySQL, that kind of stuff) (and then perhaps some web frameworks based on other programming languages, like Django for Python or Ruby on Rails). That's a pretty long time from now, though.

That's assuming you want to go with a LAMP software stack (Linux-Apache-MySQL-PHP or something like that) which is what much of the web runs on. You can certainly go the Microsoft route with things like IIS and ASP.NET, but I don't know if that's the way to go (my experience is exclusively LAMP).

That said, HTML first, then PHP and JS, then databases, and you should have a working knowledge at that point.

The W3Schools stuff is pretty good for HTML, dunno about PHP (I like [this tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/627)) and Javascript (I'm sure Mozilla has some pretty great stuff on that).

Comment: Learned all my Html/Css/Javascript from W3schools!