# Designing a professional website

Tags: javascript, css, html, xhtml

I want to make a tech news website.

I started learning PHP, and since I already know how to program, I learned big amount of it yesterday. Now I want to focus more on the design first (HTML, CSS, JS, etc...) I already know these two, I have to revise CSS though.

My question is: What is a good book/resource for learning how to design a website professionally. That is, assuming I already know all the basic, how do I design a professional slick website? 
I'm looking for a source/book that gives tips, tricks, recommendations, etc...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best PHP programming book?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90924/what-is-the-best-php-programming-book)

Comment: @fredley: Nope.  Where is the design question in that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672024/good-web-designing-books-for-programmers, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431700/book-recommendation-web-design, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034758/what-are-the-best-web-design-sites, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214509/books-for-web-application-development, and many more on this site. A search will result in many questions similar to yours with lots of great recommendations. good luck.

Comment: Yes, I am already surfing the search results. Thank you. I'm keeping the question in case there is any new/more recommendations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would recommend using Wordpress as the basis of your site, then modifying it or creating plugins as you see fit.  It will save you a LOT of time. You can then look at themes for it, modify them or create your own.

If, however, you are serious about building your own platform then, design wise, one of the most helpful things I find is to just surf the net, note down which bits of which websites look good then figure out how they work.  To do this simply install [Firefox](http://www.mozilla-europe.org/en/firefox/) and [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) then, using their DOM and CSS explorer you can quickly figure out how it works, replicate it, tinker with it, or modify it for your own use.

Comment: Not quite what the question asks, but good advice nonetheless. +1

Comment: Thank you :) I'm willing to use Joomla as I was told it's more powerful.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/  is a very good resource

Comment: I've seen it recommended many times. Will def. look at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the following books:

- [HTML5 For Web Designers](http://books.alistapart.com/products/html5-for-web-designers) by Jeremy
  Keith
- [CSS3 For Web Designers](http://books.alistapart.com/products/css3-for-web-designers) by Dan
  Cederholm
- [jQuery: Novice to Ninja](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/jquery1/) by Earle Castledine, Craig Sharkie
- [PHP In Action](http://www.manning.com/reiersol/) by Dagfinn Reiersol, Marcus Baker and Chris Shiflett
- [Smashing CS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/books/smashing/)S by Eric A. Meyer
- [The Web Designer's Idea Book Vol. 2](http://dmdthebook.com/books/volume-2/)
  by Patrick McNeil
- [Designing Brand Identity](http://alinawheeler.com/) by Alina
  Wheeler

Of course, you can find these books on many online stores such as [Amazon](http://Amazon.com).

You could adventure yourself into a Content Management System (CMS) such as:

- [SilverStripe](http://silverstripe.org) (more geared towards programmers)
- [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/)
- [WordPress](http://wordpress.com/) (more geared towards blogs)
- [Drupal](http://drupal.org/)

Also, have a look at this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034758/what-are-the-best-web-design-sites).

I'll add more resources later. ;)

Comment: I'll add links to where you can buy the books shortly. :)

Comment: Thank you very much. And I can't buy books as I can't ship them. (No Mail/Post here.)

Comment: You can get them in a PDF version too and cost less + no shipping. :D

Comment: Ohh and you save trees too! :)